# Почему в конце вывода появляется 0?

Tags: c#, массивы

Этот метод должен удалять один элемент из массива по индексу. Элемент удаляется, но в конце появляется `0`, как будто есть неинициализированный массив с дефолтным значением ноль

```
static void delet(ref int[] mass,int index)
{
    int[] arr = new int[mass.Length - 1];
    
    for(int a = 0; a < index; a++)
    {
        arr[a] = mass[a];
    }
    for(int a = index + 1; a < arr.Length; a++)
    {
        arr[a - 1] = mass[a];
    }
    mass = arr;
}
```

Comment: Второй массив не нужен: `for(int a=index+1; a<mass.Length; a++){ mass[a-1]=mass[a];}` и уменьшите длину массива.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы недобегаете в цикле, боюсь.
Во втором цикле вам следует бегать так:

```
for (int a = index + 1; a < mass.Length; a++)
```

*(Обратите внимание на замену `arr.Length` на `mass.Length`. Первый на 1 элемент короче)*
Либо так:

```
for (int a = index + 1; a <= arr.Length; a++)
```

*(Здесь обратите внимание на замену `<` на `<=`)*

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы избежать путаницы, лучше немного изменить тело функции.
По новому массиву бегаем строго по индексу, а во втором цикле смещаемся на один условно-удаленный элемент.

```cs
void delete(ref int[] mass, int index)
{
    if (index >= mass.Length)
        return;

    var len = mass.Length - 1;
    var array = new int[len];

    var i = 0;
    for (; i < index; i++)
        array[i] = mass[i];

    for (; i < len; i++)
        array[i] = mass[i + 1];

    mass = array;
}


int[] randomArray = Enumerable.Range(1, 10).Select(_ => new Random().Next(10, 20)).ToArray();

delete(ref randomArray, 5);
randomArray[randomArray.Length - 1] > 0 // true
```